# Don't understand php MySQL access denied issue

Tags: mysql

I am running MySQL Server version: 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 - (Ubuntu).

When I run this php script below with the CORRECT MySQL root user password entered I get the error: 
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

However if I change the root user to an INCORRECT value I get the MySQL error: 
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I know the MySQL root user password I'm entering is correct because I can log into both the mysql command line and phpmyadmin with it.

So the CORRECT password when received by MySQL is returning access denied using password NO but I don't understand why it would do that. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<?php 
  $dbusername = "root"; 
  $dbpassword = "password"; 
  $dbname = "DB"; 
  $dbtable = "table_name"; 

  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost",$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname); 
  // Check connection 
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
  { 
    echo " " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
  } 
?>
```

Comment: php has nothing to do with the OP removing tag

Comment: if using password: no then it don't want any password inputed.

Comment: @GeneCode `Using password: NO` means a password wasn't supplied, it doesn't mean that it doesn't want one.

Comment: yes, so when using password:no but code supplying password, it will reject.

Comment: @GeneCode nope, you got this one totally wrong.

Comment: @Shadow, Okay...

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: Using password no is part of the MySQL error message I'm receiving when the correct MySQL root user password is included in the php database connection file.   FWIW, I have tried to connect using PDO code and that did not work either.

Comment: If you printed `$dbpassword` to debug you'd probably find it was wrong (likely empty due to failed variable interpolation)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone has the same problem, it turned out that the issue was the MySQL password I was using started with the character $. The mysql command line program and phpmyadmin had no problem with accepting this character in the password but when it was included as part of a mysqli connection string (or PDO connection string for that matter) it would throw the 1045 Access Denied Using Password: NO error.

I changed the password's first character to # and no more error.

Comment: This also means your question doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by my question doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem was caused by your password starting with '$' yet the question has no indication of this. So, you did not post code that actually reproduced your problem. We had no hope of finding it. Did you print out `"$dbpassword"` yet like I suggested?

Comment: Well I didn't know that was the problem until I spent hours of trial and error and searching other stackoverflow answers until I happened to come across someone who suggested this as the solution to a similar problem.  It was something like the 5th top rated solution.

Comment: Right, which is why you are supposed to create a reproducing minimal example, otherwise you're just wasting your own time as well as ours..... That's how you find out what the problem is!! Have a good one

Comment: No I didn't print $dbpassword because I had already figured out the solution to the problem before you suggested that.

Comment: Doesn't mean you can't try it now. Then you can get to the _right_ solution, rather than just working around it with a different password. Is that not of interest?

Comment: Whatever.  Thanks for wasting your time I guess.

Comment: "Whatever"? I'm trying to help you. For free! Oh well, guess you're not interested. Take care.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you mysql / root user password is Pass123. Connect to Mysql Shell and run below sql statements.

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* to `root`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY 'Pass123';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `root`@`%` WITH GRANT OPTION;
flush privileges;
```

Now update info in php and run PHP again.

```
<?php 
$dbusername = "root"; 
$dbpassword = "Pass123"; 
$dbname = "DB"; 
$dbtable = "table_name";
```

It is recommended to create a non root user to use in the application. In my answer, I have used root as you have used this user in your question.
See [create-new-user-grant-permissions-mysql](https://kyup.com/tutorials/create-new-user-grant-permissions-mysql/)

Don't forget to change database and table names.

Comment: The `root` user shouldn't need additional privileges, but that being said using root is generally a bad plan.

Comment: I don't believe this is a root user permission problem because as I said I can log into both phpmyadmin and to the mysql command line interface using -u root -p correct_password.